# Java hosting (jetty preferred)

Tags: web-hosting, java, jetty

I currently use PairOne/OddHost for hosting, does anyone recommend anyone else for good, cheap, reliable hosting?  I would like to keep it below $100/year.

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $100/yr you could set up your own VPS with a lot of memory.  I'm a former Linode.com customer, and I was pretty happy with their service.  Granted, you have to do everything yourself, including setting up mail services and the like, but it gives you ultimate control over everything - unlike "Java hosting" sites that end up killing your tomcat server because they're taking too much CPU.

Comment: Well, I will have to check into that $100/year doesn't sound too bad and I do prefer to manage things myself since I have some experience there.

I just checked out linode.com and it looks like it would run 19.95/month or roughly 240/year.

That still isn't bad, I'll have to do more reading to see if I want to fork over the extra bucks for the service.

Thanks for the information.


Walter

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)? It isn't jetty, so maybe that is a non-starter for you but they do have both Python and Java as available environments. Your annual cost would be dependent on utilization, but once you enable the ability to be billed rather than just pure free mode, they do raise the "free" limits. It might be worth checking into.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I did some quick digging and found that JBoss Seam will run on Google App Engine; however, Hibernate will not.  I'm not ready to lose my hibernate functionality along with Envers.  I am thinking that Linode is probably the best bet.

Walter